# Pass a textfield value from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, highcharts, label

I created a field to choose a label for a highchart on wordpress backoffice like this:

```
public static function sm_register_chart() {

    $charts = array();
    if( function_exists( 'wdt_get_all_charts_nonpaged')){
        foreach( wdt_get_all_charts_nonpaged() as $table ){

            $charts[$table['id']] = $table['title'];
        }
    }
    $captions = array();

    $fields = array(

        array(
            'label' => esc_html( 'Graphic' ),
            'description' => esc_html( 'Choose the graphic' ),
            'attr'    => 'chart',
            'type'    => 'select',
            'options' => $charts,
        ),
        array(
            'label' => esc_html( 'Footer label' ),
            'description' => esc_html( 'Choose the footer label' ),
            'attr' => 'footer_caption',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),

    );
```

And i want to pass whatever is typed in `footer_caption` to this js that i took from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ur02w4j5/

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
          type: 'column',
          events: {
              load: function () {
                  var label = this.renderer.label("This text will adjust to chart resizing " +
                      "and redraws and will be visible on exported images.")
                  .css({
                      width: '400px',
                      fontSize: '9px'
                  })
                  .attr({
                      'r': 2,
                      'padding': 5
                  })
                  .add();

                  label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
                      align: 'center',
                      x: 0, // offset
                      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                      y: 0 // offset
                  }), null, 'spacingBox');

              }
          },
          marginBottom: 120
      },
      legend: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: -30
    },
```

So that instead of that `var label = this.renderer.label("This text will adjust to chart resizing")` i get the value of `footer_caption`.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var labelText = document.querySelectorAll('[footer_caption]').text()
var label = this.renderer.label(labelText)
```

But it doesn't work and im not able to even get the value i type from footer_caption

Comment: Does `document.querySelectorAll('[footer_caption]')` return anything? Or is this an empty array? Anyway, there should be rather: `document.querySelectorAll('[footer_caption]')[0].innerText;` but I'm worried that `[footer_caption]` is a wrong selector. If you could show how generated HTML element looks then I would be able to tell more about it.

Comment: see my edit, i show the full shortcode options, its where i set footer_caption

Comment: Maybe I should ask in a different way: is `footer_caption` generated on your site (so you have a tag, for example: `<div footer_caption></div>`) or it's just an element in PHP array?

Comment: just an element in php array

Comment: Then don't answers below work for you? I'm not a PHP guy, but I would use: `var label = this.renderer.label(<?php echo json_encode($fields[1]['description']); ?>;)`.

Comment: hum nope, they are not working and why 'description'?
this is the html i get on my backoffice, the value of the field is being saved i just cant pass it to the js file.
<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="footer_caption" id="shortcode-ui-footer_caption-c129" value="stack overflow test" placeholder="">

Comment: Sooo... this is the rendered HTML :) Thanks! It should be: `var labelText = 
 = document.querySelectorAll('[name=footer_caption]')[0].value;`

Comment: looked good but still didnt work. im not being able to retrieve the value i type in the textfield. footer_caption is empty when i do print_r or var_dump

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following; you may have to change the identifier for `footer_caption` depending on your own code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var footer_caption = <?= json_encode($arr['footer_caption']); ?>; 

</script>
```

And then reference the variable where it is needed in the javascript code.

Using `json_encode` ensures that illegal characters etc are correctly handled. The code above makes use of PHP quick tags more reference can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: Ok im confused. Do i had var footer_caption in the js file and then do:
var label = this.renderer.label(footer_caption) ?

Comment: yes, put this `var footer_caption = <?= json_encode($arr['footer_caption']); ?>;` in your javascript file along with the other code and then you can use that variable by referencing the javascript variable `footer_caption`. You may just need to change `$arr['footer_caption']` so that it does indeed point to the PHP variable in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode to do this

```
<script>
  var footer_caption = <?php echo json_encode($fields); ?>;
</script>
```